# Using Selenium Java to Find Element In an Array By Class Name

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

I am automating a web application, when i call element from browser using javascript classname i get the following:

[image]

Then I access the text of the first element at position 0:

[image]

but when i try to automate this process with selenium java i get the error ***"Index 0 out of bounds for length 0"*** my code is the following

```
String pattern_2 = driver.findElements(By.className("static-links__link fx-typography-meta js-header-link-service")).get(0).getText();
```

please help me! :c

Comment: https://www.thomann.de/intl/index.html

Answer (score 1):

In your code the `findElements` method finds no elements matching the passed locator.
First of all, I see you passing **multiple** class names with `By.className` while this method receives a **single** class name value. To use multiple class names you can use CSS Selector or XPath.
So, try this:

```java
String pattern_2 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".static-links__link.fx-typography-meta.js-header-link-service")).get(0).getText();
```

I can't be sure this will work since I can't see all your code, but at least the locator now mathces the method.

Comment: Thanks, I used cssSelector copying the selector instead of the class name and it found it :)